# Google Style formatting

Tags: java, formatting, visual-studio-code

I have added these two lines to my `.vscode/setting.json` file to enable the formatting feature :

```
"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml",
"java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle"
```

I am using Eclipse Key Bindings for the record. So when I do `Command + Shift + O`, I get a small bubble in my Java file saying : `Organize imports`. However when I click on it I get this error message : `Running the contributed command: '_vscode_delegate_cmd_km72g93j' failed.`.

Any idea how to solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Windows, so the keyboard shortcuts for organize imports is `Shift+Alt+O`. When i press the keys, the import sentence is organized immediately. Press Shift+Alt+O again to show the yellow bulb and choose Organize Imports, the same error occurred.

If you turn to see Log(Extension Host), you'll find the reason caused this error is `actual command NOT FOUND _vscode_delegate_cmd_kmel0ckh`:
[image]

You don't need to click the yellow bulb and choose organize imports again, but this may be an issue, and i've put it in github: [Organize imports throw the error](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1840)